# Find the two motions $\Bbb E ^2 \to \Bbb E^2 $ taking $(0,0)\to (1,2)$ and $(0,\sqrt{2}) \to (2,3)$.

Tags: geometry, rotations, isometry

Find the two motions $\Bbb E ^2 \to \Bbb E^2 $ taking $(0,0)\to (1,2)$ and $(0,\sqrt{2}) \to (2,3)$. Write each as $x \to Ax+b$ .Express them as a rotation and glide.

So far I only have that if $(0,0) \to A(0,0)+b=(1,2)$ , $b= (1,2)$.
But then $(0,\sqrt{2}) \to A(0,\sqrt{2}) +(1,2)=(2,3)$.
So $A(0,\sqrt{2}) =(1,1)$. But you can't find matrix $A$ with this since we have a $0$ in $(0,\sqrt{2}) $. I don't really know what to do

Comment: $A$ is not a general matrix. It is an orthogonal matrix. So its coefficients satisfy constraint equations that an ordinary matrix does not have to satisfy. You can use those equations, together with the equation $A(0,\sqrt{2})=(1,1)$, to solve for the coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. You can take $A$ as the rotation matrix:
$$A:=\left( \begin{array}{cc} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{array} \right)$$
Are you able to find $\theta$?

P.S. Another way (see Lee Mosher's comment below) is to take $A$ as the composition of a rotation and a glide reflection
$$A= \left( \begin{array}{cc} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 &0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks, I found it, but this is only one motion that takes (0,0) to (1,2) and $(0,\sqrt(2))$ to (2,3). How could I find the other one?

Comment: @Thomas You have a clockwise rotation of $\pi/4$ degree and then a translation.

Comment: Thanks! I just completely misunderstood the question

Comment: This answer is not quite accurate, because $A$ could also be a reflection matrix $$A:=\left( \begin{array}{cc} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & -\cos(\theta) \end{array} \right)$$ which produces the other (orientation reversing) motion of the plane taking $(0,0)$ to $(0,\sqrt{2})$.